# Dynamic Label in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I was wondering if we can change the label of the select statement like we do for data in sql select using `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE column1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Available]
```

But can we have a dynamic header something like

```
SELECT column1 AS <-- Available when 1 or Not Available when 0
```

This can be handled on the front end but its wise if we have it on backend. Any help or useful link is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `dynamic sql` and `if...else` instruction but it not make sense for me. In relational database value in the cell tells you if something is available or not. If header tells you the same as cell it's duplicate information. If you want to description of the value you can use `case` syntax instead of 0/1 value

```
SELECT CASE when column1 = 1 THEN 'Available' 
       ELSE 'Not available' 
       END AS [Available]
```

Comment: The question is about dynamic column name, not about value of column.

Comment: @Parado Actually I am populating a grid so need a header based on an external value, we can handle that on front end but on sql it would be wise but I think creating different view can help on this

Comment: @brykneval So if there are 2000 rows with value 0 and 2000 with value  1 what headers do you want to display ?

Comment: its an external value a variable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37083/discussion-between-brykneval-and-parado)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that would not make sense, as what would you expect the column name to be if you hade 2 rows, one with 1 (being available) and the other with 0(being Not Available)?

You would have to stick to something like

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN column1 = 1 
            THEN 'Available' 
        ELSE 'Not available' 
    END as Availability
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Actually I am populating a grid so need a header based on an external value, we can handle that on front end but on sql it would be wise but I think creating different view can help on this